# How do you align elements going from right to left in a horizontal layout using Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Using `layout = horizontal`, the elements within stack up starting from the left. I want to stack the elements from right to left. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your use case you could also do:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <View layout="horizontal" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" right="0">
            <View backgroundColor="red" left="0" width="20" height="20" />
            <View backgroundColor="green" left="0" width="20" height="20" />
            <View backgroundColor="blue" left="0" width="20" height="20" />
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Notice that the views themselves do not stack up from right, but by setting the parent width to `Ti.UI.SIZE` the group as a total does align right. Again, this might not be fulfil your need if you need the views themselves to stack up RTL and stil want the order in the XML to be as is.

[image]

Comment: i upvoted for not only giving the answer, but actually explaining it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no property to do this. But you can do this by a mirror trick.

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container" title="Test">
        <View id="holder">
            <View class="item" />
            <View class="item" />
            <View class="item" />
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

index.tss

```
"#holder": {
    top:"50dp",
    layout:"horizontal",
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    transform:Alloy.Globals.mirror
}
".item":{
    left:0,
    width:"20dp",
    height:"20dp",
    backgroundColor:"red",
    borderColor:"blue",
    borderWidth:"1dp"
}
```

alloy.js

```
Alloy.Globals.mirror = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().scale(-1,1);
```

Comment: This one should be the correct answer as it's a general response that would work on all scenarios especially if the content width of horizontal elements is set to Ti.UI.Size

Another point to consider is, if you have labels the transform will mirror the text also, to you should apply back the mirror on every item of the horizontal elements to mirror the text back